# Trouble setting terraform variable from CLI

Tags: terraform

My terraform project layout looks something like:

```
[project root dir]
main.tf
  - my_module [directory]:
      variables.tf
      my_instance.tf
```

In `variables.tf` I have something like this:

```
variable "foo-ami" {
  default = "ami-12345"
  description = "Super awesome AMI"
}
```

In `my_instance.tf` I reference it like so:

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
  ami = "${var.foo-ami}"
  ...
}
```

If I want to override this variable from the command line, the docs [here](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html) seem to suggest I should be able to run the following command from the top level (main.tf) location:

`terraform plan -var 'foo-ami=ami-987654'`

However, the variable switch doesn't seem to be getting picked up. The old value remains set. Further more if I remove the default setting I get an error from terraform saying it's not set, so clearly the `-var` switch isn't being picked up.

Thoughts?

TIA

Comment: In addition to @minamijoyo's answer, I wanted to add that for Terraform 0.7.x and newer, you must use HCL syntax for variables. Therefore, you want something like `-var 'foo-ami="ami-987654"'`. That is, wrap the value in double quotes so it's a valid HCL string.

Answer (score 3):

The variables of `root` and `my_module` are different. If you want to pass a variable to `my_module`, you need to specify it.

In the `main.tf`, you should set the variable as follows:

```
variable "foo-ami" {}

module "my_module" {
  source = "./my_module"
  foo-ami = "${var.foo-ami}"
  ...
}
```

For details of the module feature refer to the following documents:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html